# Como quitar la subconsulta en crear una vista de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta en MySQL

```
Select t.grupo,
   Sum(servicios.cantidad) As total
From (select distinct clv_servicio, grupo from actuacion) as t
Join servicios On t.clv_servicio = servicios.id_servicos
Group By t.grupo
```

Que funciona correctamente pero a la hora de crearla me da este error:

> #HY000View's SELECT contains subquery in the FROM clause

Hay alguna forma de modificarla para que se pueda crear la vista? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es parte de mysql al crear vistas NO puedes tener *subquerys* en tu `select`

La solución es crear dos vistas:

**Vista Uno**

```
Create view VistaUno
As
select distinct clv_servicio, grupo 
  from actuacion
```

**Vista Dos**

```
Create View VistaDos
As
Select t.grupo,
   Sum(servicios.cantidad) As total
  From VistaUno as t
  Join servicios On t.clv_servicio = servicios.id_servicos
 Group By t.grupo
```

Aquí te dejo un artículo interesante y competo sobre [creación y manipulación de vistas](http://csrg.inf.utfsm.cl/~jfuentes/_build/html/lectures/week7/lecture28.html)

Comment: Perfecto, no había pensado en esa posibilidad. Muchas Gracias

Comment: excelente! me alegro que puedas solucionarlo, edité mi respuesta y te dejo un [link](http://csrg.inf.utfsm.cl/~jfuentes/_build/html/lectures/week7/lecture28.html) a un artículo bastante lindo sobre vistas en mysql.